# AngularJS: How to conditionally apply view animations?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-animation

My question could be a little strength since I haven't found any other case like that.

I want to perform views animations, but not always. So far, I had the animation in the .css format:

```
.view.ng-enter{
    animation: view_enter @anim-view-dur;
}

.view.ng-leave{
    animation: view_leave @anim-view-dur;
}
```

So when I go from one page to another, it is performed.

The exactly case when I don't want the animation view to be applied is in a page where I have an ScrollSpy Bootstrap sidebar working. Since it's within a view, I had to do the anchor links with a function:

```
$scope.scrollTo= function (id){ 
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();
    };
```

And when this function is called, it's trigger the view animation. Is there any way to prevent from trigger the view animation in this case?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to prevent the `scrollTo` function from triggering the view reload, or is that something that is required?

Comment: @tasseKATT I've tried, using `$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    });` , but then it never change the route, like the links become freeze. Is there any other way to prevent the view reload? Thanks

Comment: Hard to say if it fits your use case, but try setting `reloadOnSearch` to `false` for the route. For example: `templateUrl: 'template.html', controller: 'SomeController', reloadOnSearch: false`

Comment: If you need `reloadOnSearch` to be `true` and want to prevent the view animation that should be solvable too, just let me know.

Comment: Hi @tasseKATT, that made it work!!!!! I'm working in my first AngularJS project and I realize that is very powerful, tough to do some simple things sometimes you have to search a lot for it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was working for me:

```
// Routes config
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
        controller : "MyController"
        reloadOnSearch : true         
    })
});
```

You could also use this in [router-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)